# Use same method in before insert Apex code and in button

Tags: apex, trigger, class, button, method

Maybe a simple question: is there a way I can use the same method to create/update records in a before trigger and in a button?

I have an Apex class. Let's call it Stuff.apxc.

```
public class Stuff {
    public static void doStuff(List<SObject> newObjs) {
        List<Custom_Object__c> customObj = (List<Custom_Object__c>) newObjs;
        // do things like update related records and created other objects, etc. etc.
    }
}
```

I currently call this method in a before insert trigger.

```
trigger myTrigger on Custom_Object__c (before insert) {
    Stuff.doStuff(Trigger.new);
}
```

So far so good. Everything works.

Now, there are scenarios where Salesforce users will need to manually review the information in the Custom_Object__c and perhaps fill in some fields or create some Contact or Account records, and for very specific reasons, we cannot automate this.

Once users have finished their review, I want to enable users to re-run the doStuff code by means of a button. However, there are update statements that write information to the Custom_Object__c record would need to be explicitly used in the button that are not used in the before insert trigger.

So is this possible? Is there a prescribed workaround for this?

Comment: Welcome! I'm not quite clear on this quote `there are insert statements that would need to be explicitly used in the button that are not used in the before insert trigger`? Are you just referring to the fact that your method relies on the custom object to be inserted?

Comment: Does "button" mean Quick Action or Custom Button here?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - I updated the wording, so hopefully it's clearer. I am referring to how in a before insert trigger I do not need to explicitly update the record being inserted by means of an update statement, while if I call this method with a custom button/Lightning Component, I would need to use update statements.

Comment: @cropredy - I mean a custom button/Lightning Component, not a quick action.

Comment: LWC can invoke apex, apex can do update work, then call Stuff.doStuff.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Visualforce extension class that includes a method that
   calls your `Stuff.doStuff` method. The method can then return a
   pagereference back to the calling page.
2. Create a visualforce page that implements the `<apex:page extensions="yourExtensionClass" standardController="Your_Object__c" action="yourExtensionMethodHere">` tag.
3. Create a custom button to your Visualforce page and add to your layout